# get dynamic values from multyple elements with same Id or Class

Tags: javascript

i have two functions here first one is working (but i think it is not effective approach to do this) , but second one is not giving all values in list it push only last tagname value, but i want all values in list . So is there any effective solution of this approach.

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="main">         
            <label class="ac_triggers">
            <label style="color: yellow;">note</label><br><br>
            <table style="width: 100%">
             <tr>
              <td id='values1'>{{Sum_energy|floatformat:2}}</td>
                <td id='values2'>{{std_energy|floatformat:1}}</td>
            </tr><tr>
              
                <td id='values4'>{{Sum_cab|floatformat:2}}</td>
                <td id='values5'>{{std_cab}}</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td id='values'>{{Sum_nic|floatformat:2}}</td>
                <td id='values'>{{std_nic}}</td>
            </tr>
            </table><br><br>
            </label>
            <a href="food_input"><button id="submit">Submit</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
function save(){
    // var new_data = $('#values').text();
    var valuesList = []
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    valuesList.push($('#values'+i).text());
}
    console.log(valuesList)
}
// function save(){
//  var listValue =[];
//  var links = $('#values').text();
//  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
//    var link = links[i];
//   listValue.push(link) ;
//  } 
//  console.log(listValue);
// }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop the elements use `class`. Because `id` should be unique. In your second method you are targeting only the last element and that also having wrong usage of `id`. As per my understanding you want to loop all your `td` element and get the text and add it into one array.

I have given the sample how you can use the class and get the text element on it.

```js
 function save(){
  var listValue =[];
  $('.values').each(function(e){
    listValue.push($(this).text()) ; 
  });  
  console.log(listValue);
 }
 save();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div id="main">         
            <label class="ac_triggers">
            <label style="color: yellow;">note</label><br><br>
            <table style="width: 100%">
             <tr>
              <td class='values'>Test1</td>
                <td class='values'>100</td>
            </tr><tr>
              
                <td class='values'>Test2</td>
                <td class='values'>200</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td class='values'>Test3</td>
                <td class='values'>300</td>
            </tr>
            </table><br><br>
            </label>
            <a href="food_input"><button id="submit">Submit</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```